# Help resolving a success probability case!

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

I am having problems answering this exercise, what is the thinking process that i have to adopt? how do i apply the binomial distribution?

Problem:
It is known from the past experience that the probability that a startup company is successful is 0.2 if its business is hard science based and 0.1 if it is not. It is also known that 1/4 of the startups are hard science based. Determine the probability that a startup is successful.

Comment: Suppose there are $40$ startups. How man do you expect to be successful? What does this say of the probability of a startup to be successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will need to use weighted probabilities. The answer to your problem is
$$P(successful)=0.25P(successful|science-based)+0.75P(successful|non-science-based)$$
You already stated in the given of the problem that
$$P(successful|science-based)=0.2$$
and
$$P(successful|non-science-based)=0.1$$
So substitute in to get the final answer:
$$P(successful)=0.25(0.2)+0.75(0.1)$$
$$P(successful)=0.05+0.075$$
$$P(successful)=0.125=\frac{1}{8}$$
Which is the final answer.